# usage of allure and lure

Tags: meaning, word-choice, grammar, word-usage, differences

What is difference between *lur*e and *allure* ? Dictionaries refer that both words convey message to attract. However I found that lure is often used to attract through false or exaggerated promises or persuasion. Is it right or not ?

For instance :

> He **lured** both girls into his car under the guise he was a punter and then drove them several miles away.

Is it appropriate to use *lure* only in false promising manner and *allure* in contrast ?

For instance:

> I am **allured** by the a dramatic landscape of magnificent mountains.

Is it correct ?

Or both words can be used interchangeably as there is no difference ? I can't distinguish the usage of these words. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"To lure" is a verb: I lure someone to me.

"Allure" is a quality: I have an allure about me.

"To be allured" is to be affected by the quality "allure"